# Monotouch PushSharp Problems

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I am using the PushSharp library and am having issues getting the sample to send over a message.

I am getting a deviceToken just fine, but when I try and send a message to it via the PushSharp example I get an error and no message is pushed to my iPad.

```
    push.QueueNotification(NotificationFactory.Apple()
            .ForDeviceToken("c27d5fc52e4fce7a3dcf2306d984a90179ba0bde443e2c6f6d7399cb02d13ad5")
            .WithAlert("1 Alert Text!")
            .WithSound("default")
            .WithBadge(7));
```

Here is the console output

```
Waiting for Queue to Finish... 
Sent: Apple -> {"aps":{"alert":"1 Alert Text!","badge":7,"sound":"default"}}
Queue Finished, press return to exit...
Device Subscription Expired: Apple -> c27d5fc52e4fce7a3dcf2306d984a90179ba0bde44
3e2c6f6d7399cb02d13ad5
```

Any ideas on where to even start looking?

Thanks,

Comment: `Device Subscription Expired: Apple` sounds like the iPad's subscription to the content has expired and needs to be renewed.

Comment: It just got that token from the APNS just a few minutes before I got the sample setup. How can you force apple to give a new subscription?

Comment: I dont' know what actually fixed it, but I deleted the app from the device, re-did the provision profile deployment, rebuilt, and then it started working.... Ugh... Why does apple have to be so complicated.